# Calculate Logarithm in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, sum, where-clause

I am trying to put an equation into SQL but it gives me an error. Below is my equation:

```
CREATE TABLE INFORGAIN (WORD, DMS, NOTDMS, INFO_G) AS
SELECT WORD, DMS, NOTDMS, D_FREQ FROM CONTIGENCY_T
WHERE
INFO_G=((D_FREQ/132299)*LOG(D_FREQ/132299))+(D_FREQ/132299)*((DMS/D_FREQ)*LOG(DMS/D_FREQ))+(NOTDMS/132299)*((9910-DMS)/D_FREQ*LOG((9910-DMS)/D_FREQ));
```

Here is the error: `Error at Command Line:9 Column:18
Error report:
SQL Error: ORA-00920: invalid relational operator
00920. 00000 -  "invalid relational operator"`. 
The error is the `SUM`. Thanks.

Comment: The error is self explanatory, you can't do sum in the where clause, at least not like that, perhaps if you included more information about what exactly you're trying to achieve, a HAVING clause may be more appropriate.

Comment: What are you trying to do?in general you use `WHERE something=soemthingelse`,besides aggregate functions without group by issue.

Comment: Why is the title about a completely different error code and message?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I tried twice with different queries. Updated the latest problem in the post.

Comment: you missed to specify the right hand operand in your where clause expression. sql doesnt have unary operators. It has to be _where a=0_ not _where a_

Comment: Do you mean like what I updated? If not, could you please edit my query? I keeps giving me errors for using `*`. Thanks.

Comment: you still get the same error?

Comment: Yes, and the error points to `*`.

Comment: try using brackets for the select statement.

Comment: Still having the same problem, pointing to the same place. Should I indent? Tried it on `INFO_G` expression, didn't work either...

Comment: can u do a [sql fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8) with ur table structure in select query and send us the updated URL.?

Comment: Have never used it before.My tables are huge, how do I put it in sql fiddle?

Comment: just the ddl is enough.

Answer (score 2):

It is not possible to use aggregate functions in a where clause since the where clause runs before the aggregates.  You can likely get the same result by using the aggregate functions in a HAVING clause instead.

The order of operations for a sql statement is:
FROM
WHERE
GROUP BY
HAVING
SELECT
ORDER BY.

This means you can't use a column alias in a WHERE clause but you can in an order by since the SELECT alias columns.  Aggregate functions happen in the group by section.  If you don't include a group by statement sql uses your entire result set like in a 
          `select count(*) from table` 
statement.  Aggregate function can therefore be used in any statement after the group by section.  HAVING, SELECT and ORDER BY are all fair game.

Comment: I am pretty new to SQL. By saying "aggregate function" do you mean `SUM`. Just noticed that I do not need `SUM`. I updated my code it still gives me an error. I also tried to add base in the format of `(10)` or '[10]', none of them worked.

Comment: By aggregate function I mean any function that operates on more than one row.  Sum, count, min, max, avg...